# How to select only one checkbox out on four in android at run time

Tags: android

I want to select one checkbox out of four checkboxes.
And save the value in a variable. All four checkboxes includes TextView below them aligned horizontally.

Comment: why are you using checkbox for this functionality use radio buttons

Comment: you can use radio group

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We are here to help in your code. Please provide your code of whatever you have tried so someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can user radio group like this

java code for your activity

```
 final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) cancelDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancle_booking_radio_group);
    radioChangePlan = (RadioButton) cancelDialog.findViewById(R.id.radioChangePlan);
    radioBetterDeal = (RadioButton) cancelDialog.findViewById(R.id.radioBetterDeal);
    radioDiffHotel = (RadioButton) cancelDialog.findViewById(R.id.radioDiffHotel);
    radioBookingMistake = (RadioButton) cancelDialog.findViewById(R.id.radioBookingMistake);
    radioOther = (RadioButton) cancelDialog.findViewById(R.id.radioOther);

    tvHideCancelDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cancelDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
            int index = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                   // first radio button selected
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // second radio button selected
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // third radio button selected
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // forth radio button selected
                    break;
                case 4:
                    // fifth radio button selected
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

**xml layout**

```
        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/cancle_booking_radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioChangePlan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/change_in_plan" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBetterDeal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/found_a_better_deal" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioDiffHotel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/want_to_book_a_differnt_hotel" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBookingMistake"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/booking_created_by_mistake" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioOther"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/other" />


    </RadioGroup>
```